# Конвертация строки в регулярное выражение

Tags: php, eval

Пробую так:

```
<?php
    echo eval('return '.$_GET['expression'].';');
?>
```

В результате ошибка:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting ';' in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\ing.php(3) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: Тут не в регулярное выражение, вы пытаетесь выполнить код, который был передан Get-ом. Что вы отправляете в запросе? И я надеюсь,  вы этот код не на реальный проект выкатываете, а то php-injection во всей красе

Comment: Ничего не понимаю, зачем так делать, когда моно просто `echo $_GET['expression'];` - к тому-же, как вам и подметили инъекции не избежать. Тот кто отправит вам `php` код в гет, может взломать или убить ваш сервер.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка происходит скорее всего потому, что само регулярное выражение не обрамлено в кавычки/апострофы. Попробуйте:

```
<?php
echo eval('return "'.$_GET['expression'].'";');
?>
```